# What are these hooks for, on the Manfrotto 055XB?

Tags: tripod, manfrotto

I have the Manfrotto 055XB legs, and there are 2 hooks on the base.

This one looks like it's mainly to hang weight from to help increase stability.
[image]

But this one I'm unsure of. It's not rigid, and if you pull on it, it flexes. It feels like if any weight/force is applied, it would pop off the base. Does anyone know what attaches to this one?

[image]

Comment: Is that not where the strap (MSTRAP-1 or similar) attaches?

Comment: @StanRogers It looks like you're correct. It sure doesn't give a feeling of confidence as much as it moves by touching it, and how much it flexes when I pull on it. But, I searched for "MStrap-1" and came up with a few pictures of straps hooked to it. Thanks!

Comment: It's amazing what altogether too many non-buying visits to the local camera emporium (well, *emporia*, since I could probably hit both the Henry's and Vistek main stores with a rock from home) and a not-quite-useless-yet memory can be good for. I don't completely trust my memory, but sometimes it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Stan Rogers - I googled for "MStrap-1" and got images of Manfrotto carrying straps attached to this hook. Though it doesn't feel like a strong attachment point, clearly it's capable of carrying the tripod around on.

[image: enter link description here]

[Manfrotto MStrap-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004TL3R24) on Amazon

Comment: It's fine, I have the strap for my Manfrotto 190CXPRO3 in the same configuration and it has had no issues though thick and thin.